# How to smoothly rotate line without interpolate method on React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a line on the middle of my screen, that works with Accelerometer and moves this top or bottom and also supposed to rotate. I am using LayoutAnimation, but seems like this method doesn't allow me to rotate my line smoothly, it goes well with 'top' property, but it's not working with rotation

I've tried to install react-native-canvas, but this package wrecks my app at all so I have to recreate it ;D (it pissed me off). 
Also I tried to make this animation with interpolate, but it seems like working for fixed degrees and looks weird

```
componentDidMount(){
    setUpdateIntervalForType(SensorTypes.accelerometer, 150);
    const subscription = accelerometer.subscribe(({ x, y, z }) =>{
        let d = getAngles(x,y,z);
        this.updateValues(d.roll,d.pitch);
      }
    );
  }

updateValues(roll,pitch){
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(CustomLayoutAnimation)
    this.setState({roll,pitch})
  }

render() {

    return (
...
    {<View style={{position:"relative",top:calculateOffset(this.state.roll,this.state.screenOffset)+"%",width:"80%",height:4,backgroundColor:"orange",transform:[{rotate:`${this.state.pitch}deg`}]}} />}
...
);
  }
```

I'm on search for some working package to work with or way to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you show the current output screenshot for more detail without rotating effect?

Comment: sure, https://imgur.com/WYZdrQA

Comment: You just want to rotate the line?

Comment: Yes, I actualy did this with old and new values via interpolate, but it's weird that it looks so complicated, is there any fine decision?

Comment: You should use directly degree in your interpolation instead of concatenating your number in a string. Take a look at this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37445916/5555458)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<View
   style={{
      position:"relative",
      top: calculateOffset(this.state.roll,this.state.screenOffset)+"%",
      width: "80%",
      height: "80%",
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
      justifyContent: "center",
      transform:[{rotate:`${this.state.pitch}deg`}]}}
   }}
>
   <View
      style={{
         height: 4,
         backgroundColor: "orange",
         width: "100%"
      }}
   />
</View>
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this with interpolation and Animated API.
It looks weird though, but works ;)