# React Native Rotate Animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated, react-native-animatable, react-animations

I am trying to create an animation using hooks, but I have problems with my code.
can anybody help me?
No error appears when I test, but the image does not appear.
I'm trying to make a picture rotate on my loading screen.

```
export default function SplashLoading() {
  const [rotateValue, setRotateValue] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
  useEffect(() => {
    StartImageRotate();
  }, []);

  function StartImageRotate() {
    rotateValue.setValue(0);

    Animated.timing(rotateValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 3000,
      easing: Easing.linear,
    }).start(() => StartImageRotate());
  }

  const RotateData = rotateValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: ["0deg", "360deg"],
  });

  return (
    <Container>
      <Animated.Image
        style={{
          height: 230,
          transform: [{ rotate: RotateData }],
          width: 250,
        }}
        source={{ uri: "./gear.png" }}
      />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do image rotation using hooks, so I've encountered this [image rotation in class component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445090/react-native-how-do-you-animate-the-rotation-of-an-image), turns out the issue was in how we provide the image source

```
<Animated.Image
    style={{
      height: 230,
      transform: [{ rotate: RotateData }],
      width: 250,
    }}
    source={{ uri: "./gear.png" }}
  />
```

instead of using uri, import the image at the top then using it in the Animated.Image

```
import GearPng from "./gear.png";


<Animated.Image
    style={{
      height: 230,
      transform: [{ rotate: RotateData }],
      width: 250,
    }}
    source={GearPng}
  />
```

**side note**: you can wrap the `Animated.timing` inside a `Animated.loop` so it keeps on repeating

```
Animated.loop(
  Animated.timing(rotateValue, {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: 3000,
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  })
 ).start();
};
```